# Langchain OpenAI ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

```
!pip install langchain openai  --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

```py
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
llm = OpenAI()
```

ERROR:

```bash
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_community/llms/openai.py in validate_environment(cls, values)
    298         try:
--> 299             import openai
    300         except ImportError:

10 frames
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_community/llms/openai.py in validate_environment(cls, values)
    299             import openai
    300         except ImportError:
--> 301             raise ImportError(
    302                 "Could not import openai python package. "
    303                 "Please install it with `pip install openai`."

ImportError: Could not import openai python package. Please install it with `pip install openai`.
```

Comment: Remove `--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver`

Comment: could you post your env? 
pip list env

Answer (score 1):

Try update dependencies:

```
pip install --upgrade openai langchain
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a problem related to dependencies versions. I suggest you:

1. Generate a requirements file with the pip-compile tool.

Just create a requirements.in file and run the following:

```
pip install pip-tools
pip-compile requirements.in --verbose
```

This should generate the correct version/packages to run your app.

2. If the problem persists I recommend you the following versions that I recently tested in a project with Python 3.10 in Linux Ubuntu.

```
chainlit~=0.7.604
openai~=1.3.5
langchain~=0.0.339
```